# how to define custom model's batch prediction on Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm having trouble understanding how to perform batch predictions using a custom model in Vertex AI. I've understood that for non-custom models, it's sufficient to send a curl command for batch inference, but I don't know how to define the process for batch inference in a custom model. I know how to define the process for regular online inference, and I have been able to create a custom model and perform online inference with it.

Or, could it be that I am misunderstanding something?